# Bamboo Workspace Handling

Tags: bamboo

I'm not really sure if I got bamboos workspace handling right...
We have the following situation:

```
stage1:
 job1: scm checkout 
stage2:
 job2: build1 
 job3: build2
stage3: 
 job4: build3
 job5: build4
```

The repositorys size is about ~1,5 gb. Therefore, after every build, I want to delete everything except the build artefacts on my agent. But if I delete something on my agent in stage2, my jobs in stage 3 only get the "cleaned" ws. Is this default behaviour? And if yes, how can I prevent that my agent gets "dumped"?
x jobs = x*1,5gb ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the working dir, go to **Job configuration** / **Miscellaneous tab** and check **Clean working directory after each build**.

I haven't found this option in the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo0600/configuring-miscellaneous-settings-for-a-job-894742528.html), anyway its there (Bamboo 6.0.3)

Also note, that if you have more than one **agent**, jobs might run on any of them (concurrently). So *job1* (checkout) could theoretically run on another machine, than the rest. You can solve that with **Tasks**, which always run inside one Job, thus one agent.